# Get all occurrences of a string within a directory(including subdirectories) in .gz file using bash?

Tags: bash, shell, find, zgrep

I want to find all the occurrences of "getId" inside a directory which has subdirectories as follows:

```
*/*/*/*/*/*/myfile.gz
```

i tried [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187742/how-do-i-grep-recursively-through-gz-files)find -name *myfile.gz -print0 | xargs -0 zgrep -i "getId" but it didn't work. Can anyone tell me the best and simplest approach to get this?

Comment: what error did you get? and Also you need to add the directory as well. try::     find . -name "myFile.gz" -type f -exec zgrep -i getSorById {} \;    also in some , you may have to use gzgrep

Comment: if you would like to print only the files which have that keyword use grep -il . also if that is what you require you can use grep -ril "keyword" *

Comment: @abhishekphukan it is not giving the expected result although it is not throwing any error.

Comment: Could you please share the expected output

Answer (score 2):

```
find ./ -name '*gz' -exec zgrep -aiH 'getSorById' {} \;
```

find allows you to execute a command on the file using "-exe" and it replaces "{}" with the file name, you terminate the command with "\;"

I added "-H" to zgrep so it also prints out the file path when it has a match, as its helpful. "-a" treats binary files as text (since you might get tar-ed gzipped files)

Lastly, its best to quote your strings in case bash starts globbing them.

https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep
https://linux.die.net/man/1/find

Answer (score 0):

Use the following **find** approach:

```
find . -name *myfile.gz -exec zgrep -ai 'getSORByID' {} \;
```

This will print all possible lines containing `getSORByID` substring